# Extract part of Column Awk

Tags: linux, awk

I am trying to count the number of occurrences per second in a log file for a term searched.  I've been using AWK and have the issue of the time stamp being locate in a column with additional information.  Is it possible to get the number of occurrences per second by only looking for the time pattern 00:00:00 - 24:00:00?

Data example:

```
[01/May/2018:23:59:59.532
[01/May/2018:23:59:59.848
[01/May/2018:23:59:59.851
[01/May/2018:23:59:59.911
[01/May/2018:23:59:59.923
[01/May/2018:23:59:59.986
[01/May/2018:23:59:59.988
[01/May/2018:23:59:59.756
[01/May/2018:23:59:59.786
[01/May/2018:23:59:59.883
```

So far I can extract the data easily enough using:

```
awk '/00:00:00/,/24:00:00/{if(/search_term/) a[$4]++} END{for(k in a) print k " - " a[k]}' file.log |sort
```

This will return:

```
[02/May/2018:10:40:05.903 - 1
[02/May/2018:10:40:05.949 - 1
[02/May/2018:10:40:05.975 - 1
[02/May/2018:10:40:05.982 - 2
[02/May/2018:10:40:06.022 - 1
[02/May/2018:10:40:06.051 - 1
[02/May/2018:10:40:06.054 - 1
[02/May/2018:10:40:06.086 - 1
[02/May/2018:10:40:06.094 - 1
[02/May/2018:10:40:06.126 - 1
```

What I'm aiming for is more:

```
10:40:05 - 5
10:40:06 - 6
```

No idea if I'm even thinking about this correctly.  New to AWK in general.

Comment: If you could chop off the part after the seconds, would that be sufficient to make the rest of your code work?

Comment: Yeah I was wondering if it would be easier to just chop off the .xxx if possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use colon and dot as the field separators, and we have hours in col2, minutes in col3 and seconds in col4

```
awk -F'[:.]' '
    {count[$2 ":" $3 ":" $4]++} 
    END {for (time in count) print time " - " count[time]}
' file
```

```
10:40:05 - 4
10:40:06 - 6
```

Output will not necessarily be sorted. If you're using GNU awk, use

```
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
    for (time in count) 
        print time " - " count[time]
}
```

([reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html#Controlling-Scanning)),
or simply pipe the output to `| sort`

Comment: Yup.  Better approach than mine :)

Answer (score -1):

One thing you can do is this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS = "1 11 1 12"} {print $4}' datetimes
```

Specify the field widths and then this will give you your time, for example.  If you don't care about milliseconds, then `"1 11 1 8 4"`

Answer (score -1):

You can use substr for the line as index of an array. for example, you have this file

```
cat 1.txt
[01/May/2018:23:59:59.532
[01/May/2018:01:59:59.848
[01/May/2018:02:59:59.851
[01/May/2018:02:59:59.911
[01/May/2018:02:59:59.923
[01/May/2018:02:00:59.986
```

you can use an awk command like this

```
cat 1.txt | awk '{a[substr($0,index($0,":")+1,8)]++} END{for(i in a) print i" - "a[i]}'
```

where substr($0,index($0,":")+1,8) cuts 8 chars from the occurrence of the first ":", use this as index of the array